# Handle Outlook MailItem Send Event in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm attempting to find a way to catch the `MailItem.Send` event in Outlook from Access.  I've created a class that sets up the objects and that works fine, but the event handler doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Here's the class I created (named `OutlookHandler`):

```
Public WithEvents app As Outlook.Application
Public WithEvents msg As Outlook.MailItem


Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set msg = app.CreateItem(olMailItem)

End Sub


Private Sub msg_Send(Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "Message Sent!"

End Sub
```

And here is the function where I create an instance of that class:

```
Public Function test()

    Dim ol As New OutlookHandler

        With ol.msg
            .To = "mike@anywhere.com"
            .Subject = "outlook event test"
            .Display
        End With


End Function
```

When I run `test`, the email creates and displays.  When I hit send in the email, the email sends but the message box never creates.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `ol variable` public in this way:

```
Dim ol As OutlookHandler
Public Function test()

    'Dim ol  As New OutlookHandler
    Set ol = New OutlookHandler

        With ol.msg
            .To = "mike@anywhere.com"
            .Subject = "outlook event test"
            .Display
        End With


End Function
```

Comment: I don't think that the `ol variable` actually has to be public.  It does need to be set to a new instance after being dimmed but you can dim it inside the test function

Comment: @HelloW - if you `Dim ol` inside `test` then it's not Global and it goes out of scope as soon as `test` completes. Once it's out of scope it's not available to respond to any events.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for that explanation.  I wasn't seeing that detail.